# WPF DatePicker - autocorrect options

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datepicker, culture, date-formatting

I have a WPF DatePicker object.

```
<DatePicker Name="dtp_FilterByDate" />
```

and

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Filter by date..." />
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
 Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat = {}{0:yyyy-MM-dd}, FallbackValue='1900-01-01', TargetNullValue='Enter a date...', 
 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

When I manually enter a date into the box it automatically corrects it (I understand that it uses Date.Parse then formats it as I specify above), but it's ignoring the fact that my PC's culture is en-GB.

For example, If I enter

```
07/10/1988
```

it autocorrects it to

```
1988-07-10
```

i.e setting the month to 7 and the day to 10 - which is not expected behaviour for my PC's "en-GB" culture - which expects 1988-10-07 for the yyyy-MM-dd format specified.

If I enter

```
23/05/2007
```

The DatePicker shows an error, rather than parsing correctly.

Is there a way to set the culture for the datepicker (or generally for all Date.Parse calls in the application) manually, either to match my PC's or even to specify en-GB in all cases?

***Edit - more information***

```
DirectCast(dtp_FilterByDate.Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", dtp_FilterByDate), TextBox)
```

shows me that the Language is "en-US" - but I don't know why this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just realised that I can update my style to do this.

Do the following:

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{...}" Language="en-GB"/>
```